# Нажатие кнопки в окне приложения

Tags: java

Подскажите библиотеку на Jave для нажатия кнопки или клик в окне.
Например имеется калькулятор,и необходимо нажать кнопку 1 и кликнуть на плюс.
Буду особо благодарен за пример любого кода по этому вопросу.
Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109274/programmatically-clicking-a-gui-button-in-java-swing

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать JavaFX, вам необходимо вешать "слушателей" на клавиатуру и все, тут пример простой программы без графического интерфейса, но есть "слушатели", как по мне хороший и простой пример, а пример с наглядным GUI на библиотеке JavaFX в интернете очень много. Удачи.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Nicholas White
 */
public class KeyBoard extends Application {

    private HashMap<KeyCode, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<>();

    public void writeKeyCode(){
        if(isPressed(KeyCode.UP)){
            System.out.println("UP");
        } else if(isPressed(KeyCode.DOWN)){
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        } else if(isPressed(KeyCode.LEFT)){
            System.out.println("LEFT");
        } else if(isPressed(KeyCode.RIGHT)){
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
        }
    }

    public boolean isPressed(KeyCode key){
        return keys.getOrDefault(key, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            keys.put(event.getCode(), true);
            writeKeyCode();
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            keys.put(event.getCode(), false);
        });


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```